# Escape the wildcarded characters using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have two files exp.txt and log.txt
The contents of the two files are as follows

```
exp.txt
This file contains * and *

log.txt
This file contains 1322566331 and 236
```

How can I compare both the files such that I get the answer as 'same'. The number 1322566331 and 236 can be of variable length.

I think that I cannot use regex because the exp.txt and log.txt can contain different text. My ultimate goal is to successfully use wildcard character such that there is upon comparing the two files there is no difference between them.

Comment: Your idea will most probably work; have you tried it?

Comment: The problem is the text can also contain some numbers which I dont want to wilcard or the text can be different. I am not sure about regex as a solution

Comment: You have two files, both with lines such as `"Foo <number> and <number>"`. If I understood your problem, you could simply delete all such sentences, and later try the match. Something like `diff <(sed 's/Foo [0-9]* and [0-9]*//g' file1) <(sed 's/Foo [0-9]* and [0-9]*//g' file2)` should be able to do it. (You may need to maintain the structure of the sentence, but that'd be simply a matter of deleting only the numbers).

Comment: It sounds like `exp.txt` is a template, and `log.txt` is generated from that template, and you want to verify that no other changes were made to `log.txt` other than having some placeholders filled with real values. Can you regenerate another copy of `log.txt` using the same data, then check if `log.txt` and you new file are identical?

Comment: I cannot generate another copy of log.txt

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `exp.txt` is like a template, and you'd like to check if `log.txt` matches or not. If you write `exp.txt` like this:

```
This file contains [^ ]+ and [^ ]+
```

... then you can check if `log.txt` matches like this:

```
grep -Eqf exp.txt jack.txt && echo matches || echo not
```

For example:

```
$ echo 'This file contains 1322566331 and 236' > a.txt
$ echo hello > b.txt 
$ grep -Eqf exp.txt a.txt && echo matches || echo not
matches
$ grep -Eqf exp.txt b.txt && echo matches || echo not
not
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed "s/[*]/[^ ]\{1,\}/g" exp.txt | while read ThisExp
 do
   sed "s/\(^${ThisExp}$\)/Same: \1/p;t;s/.*/Different/" log.txt
 done
```

if `*` is only digit `sed "s/[*]/[0-9]\{1,\}/g"`

The second sed is a sample and could be adapted to your need

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my ($exp, $log) = <>; 
$exp =~ s/([^*]*)/\Q$1\E/g;
$exp =~ s/\*/\\d+/g;
if ( $log =~ m/$exp/ ) { 
    print "Same\n";
}
```

It reads both lines to variables, replace wilcards with a regular expression that matches digits (`\d+`) and escape all other content with `quotemeta()` equivalent `\Q` and `\E`. Then I use a regular expression matching to check if they are equal.

It yields:

```
Same
```